# Functions and loops for filtering

Tags: python, function, loops, filtering

Working on a homework assignment and am at a loss. Included is a screenshot of the code in Enthought Canopy. I'm confused on how to code out the rest of the function to enable loop filtering. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNO53.png)

Comment: split the string into words, now iterate over words and check for each word if they start with the letter 'o' and store them to a dictionary. Finally print all the  keys from the dictionary

Comment: Do **not post images of code**, especially not *links to images of code*. Post the code as formatted text *in the question itself*.

Comment: In addition to including the actual code, please explain what you've tried and specifically where you're confused.

Comment: sorry about the screenshot of code. I won't do that next time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pythonic way to do this is a conditional [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
o_words = [w for w in words if w.lower().startswith('o')]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
print([elem for elem in lyrics.replace(',','').replace('.','').replace('\n',' ').split(' ') if elem.lower().startswith('o')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

print(" ".join(re.findall(r"(?:^|\s|\b)([Oo][a-zA-Z]*)(?:\s|\b|$)",lyrics)))
```

using this regular expression i got

> over ocean over over ocean Oh over ocean over over ocean Oh Oh oh Oh over ocean over over ocean Oh Oh Oh Oh